# java enumeration loop doubles up on repeat of cycle

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a trivia game in swing with CardLayout to change between screens in a single JFrame. I have a loop set to move through the states in my enumeration. Everything works quite well except for when, at the end of a game, if I choose to start a new game, it somehow goes to both the first and second states simultaneously. I'm not sure how this happens as this is the only state this happens in.

Code for main:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main 
{
public enum State {SPLASH, PREQUESTION, QUESTION, WIN, LOSS};
public static JFrame frame;
public static JPanel content;
public static JPanel neutral;
public static int event;
public static Random rn = new Random();
public static Splash splash;
public static Prequestion eventStart;
public static Question question;
public static Win win;
public static Loss loss;

public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException
{
    frame = new JFrame("DREWcathalon");

    content = new JPanel();
    neutral = new JPanel();

    CardLayout cards = new CardLayout();
    content.setLayout(cards);
    neutral.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    content.add(neutral, "neutral");

    frame.add(content);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1000, 750);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    cards.show(content, "neutral");
    State gameState = State.SPLASH;
    while (true)
    {
        switch(gameState)
        {
        case SPLASH:
            event = 0;
            splash = new Splash(content, cards);
            splash.splashSound();
            while (splash.holdState()){};
            cards.show(content, "neutral");
            gameState = State.PREQUESTION;
            splash = null;
            break;
        case PREQUESTION:
            event++;
            eventStart = new Prequestion(event, content, cards);
            while (eventStart.holdState()){};
            cards.show(content, "neutral");
            gameState = State.QUESTION;
            eventStart = null;
            break;
        case QUESTION:
            question = new Question(event, rn.nextInt(5)+1, content, cards);
            while (question.holdState()){};
            cards.show(content, "neutral");
            if (question.rightState() && event > 9)
            {
                gameState = State.WIN;
            }
            else if (question.rightState())
            {
                gameState = State.PREQUESTION;
            }
            else
            {
                gameState = State.LOSS;
            }
            question = null;
            break;
        case WIN:
            win = new Win(content, cards);
            while(win.holdState()){};
            cards.show(content, "neutral");
            gameState = State.SPLASH;
            win = null;
            break;
        case LOSS:
            loss = new Loss(content, cards);
            while(loss.holdState()){};
            cards.show(content, "neutral");
            gameState = State.SPLASH;
            loss = null;
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Code for Win:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Win 
{
static private Clip clip;
static private boolean hold = true;

public Win(JPanel content, CardLayout cards) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException
{
    JButton restart = new JButton("New Game+");
    JButton quit = new JButton("Flee");
    JLabel title = new JLabel("A Winnar is You!");
    JPanel wContent = new JPanel();

    wContent.add(title);
    wContent.add(restart);
    wContent.add(quit);
    wContent.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    content.add(wContent, "win");
    cards.show(content, "win");

    File soundFile = new File("TEST.wav");
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioIn);

    clip.start();

    restart.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (clip.getMicrosecondPosition() < clip.getMicrosecondLength()) 
            {
                clip.stop();
            }
            hold = false;
        }
    });

    quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

public boolean holdState()
{
    return hold;
}
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThomas A massive code dump like this doesn't make your problem easy to solve or very approachable. Please see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RobMurray: a good suggestion. Consider voting to close the question pending posting the MCVE.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the specific answer to your specific question, which is one reason I'm answering this as a Community Wiki, but I can state with confidence that your program structure is broken and is not written in a way that respects either object-oriented programming principles, as evidenced by your copious use of static fields, or GUI event-driven coding principles, as evidenced by your `while (true)` loop. The solution is to completely restructure your program, getting rid of your `while (true)` loop and instead use notifications / observer design pattern to drive state changes.

I can almost guarantee that if you fix these issues, especially by getting rid of the `while (true)` loop and replacing it with event notification and listening, your problem with game restart will resolve.

If you need more specific help, you'll want to create and post your valid [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (please see the link for the details). I tried doing this myself with your code, but it's taking me too long, and the effort really should be yours.

A very simplistic example that uses simple notification to change state

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main2 extends JPanel {
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private MyState myState = MyState.SPLASH;
    private MySplash mySplash = new MySplash(this);
    private MyPreQuestion myPreQuestion = new MyPreQuestion(this);
    private MyQuestion myQuestion = new MyQuestion(this);

    public Main2() {
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        add(mySplash, MyState.SPLASH.toString());
        add(myPreQuestion, MyState.PREQUESTION.toString());
        add(myQuestion, MyState.QUESTION.toString());

        mySplash.startSplashTimer();
    }

    public void next() {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < MyState.values().length; i++) {
            if (MyState.values()[i] == myState) {
                index = i;
            }
        }
        index++;
        index %= MyState.values().length;
        setState(MyState.values()[index]);
    }

    public void setState(MyState nextState) {
        myState = nextState;
        cardLayout.show(this, nextState.toString());
        if (myState == MyState.SPLASH) {
            mySplash.startSplashTimer();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Main2());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

}

enum MyState {
    SPLASH, PREQUESTION, QUESTION  // ..., WIN, LOSS
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class NextAction extends AbstractAction {
    private Main2 main;

    public NextAction(Main2 main) {
        super("Next");
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_N);
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        main.next();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
abstract class AbstractView extends JPanel {
    private Main2 main;

    public AbstractView(Main2 main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public Main2 getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void next() {
        main.next();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MySplash extends AbstractView {

    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 3000;
    private Timer timer;

    public MySplash(Main2 main) {
        super(main);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 140));
        add(new JLabel("My Splash"));        

    }

    public void startSplashTimer() {
        timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, e -> {
            next();
            timer.stop();
        });
        timer.start();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyPreQuestion extends AbstractView {

    public MyPreQuestion(Main2 main) {
        super(main);
        add(new JLabel("Prequestion"));
        add(new JButton(new NextAction(main)));
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyQuestion extends AbstractView {

    public MyQuestion(Main2 main) {
        super(main);
        add(new JLabel("Question"));
        add(new JButton(new NextAction(main)));
    }
}
```